# Validating a Win32 Window Handle

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Given a handle of type `HWND` is it possible to confirm that the handle represents a real window?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a function `IsWindow` which does exactly what you asked for.

```
BOOL isRealHandle = IsWindow(unknwodnHandle);
```

Look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528(VS.85).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Generally no. By the time you've got confirmation that a Window is valid another process/thread my come along and remove it for you.